# Meteor createContainer resubscribe for data

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

This is my createContainer wrapper:

```
export default createContainer(({params}) => {
  const currentUser = Meteor.user();

  let itemsCount = 10;
  const subs = Meteor.subscribe('items', itemsCount);
  const items = Items.find({}, {sort: {country: 1, lastUpdateCheck: -1}}).fetch();

  return {
    items,
    currentUser,
  };
}, MyComponent);
```

I would like to put **Load More** button somewhere in **MyComponent** component, and when the button is pressed increment the **itemsCount** in **createContainer** to subscribe for more data. Is it possible at all to change variable in **createContainer**? Or any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is by using a [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) to hold your `itemsCount`, then pass this `ReactiveVar` down into your `MyComponent` as a prop. When the load more button is clicked, you could change the `itemsCount` value, which will cause your `createContainer` code to re-run. Quick example:

```
const itemsCount = new ReactiveVar(10);

export default createContainer(({params}) => {
  const currentUser = Meteor.user();
  const subs = Meteor.subscribe('items', itemsCount.get());
  const items = Items.find(
    {}, 
    {sort: {country: 1, lastUpdateCheck: -1}}
  ).fetch();

  return {
    items,
    currentUser,
    itemsCount,
  };
}, MyComponent);
```

then in your `MyComponent` you would call a `this.props.itemsCount.set(X)` somewhere after the load more button is clicked.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks :-)